# Parameter metadata not available for these statement in MariaDB

Tags: java

I have a Apache camel application that is running 24*7 to poll a file from a server and process it. I am using MariaDB as a database.After deploying the application it runs perfectly but after 8-9  hours it begins to throw the following exception:
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; Parameter metadata not available for these statement; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter metadata not available for these statement.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

The problem was a misconfigured connection pool (i use C3PO). It resulted in some broken connections in the pool. MariaDB server had the option "wait_timeout" default value which disconnects idle connections after 8 hours, but C3PO did not purged connections at all. I configured C3PO to purge idle connections in a time shorter than 8 hours by setting the option `MaxIdleTime` and the exceptions went away.

The exception triggered by the MariaDB driver is not really useful about the real issue. MySQL one, which i used previously, was more explicit. That's why i concluded in an issue about connections.

So, if you use a connection pool (C3P0, Hikari or the one bundled with the MariaDB JDBC driver), check its configuration.